# swift - NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler not working, but can work in the OC

Tags: ios, swift, exception

This is catch the exception code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NdUncaughtExceptionHandler : NSObject {
}
+ (void)setDefaultHandler;
@end
```

-

```
#import "UncaughtExceptionHandler.h"

void UncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]; 
}

@implementation NdUncaughtExceptionHandler

+ (void)setDefaultHandler {
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler (&UncaughtExceptionHandler); 
}
@end
```

Call the method is `NdUncaughtExceptionHandler.setDefaultHandler()`, but does not work in the swift.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        NdUncaughtExceptionHandler.setDefaultHandler()
}
```

It can work in the Objecttive-C

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [NdUncaughtExceptionHandler setDefaultHandler];
}
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Can you describe *"does not work in Swift"* more precisely? Does it not compile, does it crash, does it not give the expected results?

Comment: My English is not good. It can be compiled and run, but can not catch the exception. But with OC, it will open the page after the application crash

Comment: What exception? How did you test it?

Comment: Trigger an error, like:  `var a = [""];    println(a[2]);`

Comment: is your crash happening at:  NdUncaughtExceptionHandler.setDefaultHandler() or is it happening when you have a NSSet Uncaught Exception somewhere else in your code?

Comment: no。This is my new discovery  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024803/swift-how-to-deal-with-uncaught-exception