# swift - How to deal with uncaught exception

Tags: swift, exception

If use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`, it only handles objective-C runtime errors.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler

`NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` can catch the exception:

```
var a: NSArray = [""]
println(a[2])
```

But `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` can not catch exceptions:

```
var a = [""]
println(a[2])
```

How swift deal with non-objective-C runtime errors(swift runtime errors)??

Comment: I have the same problem, seems that NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler does not work with swift exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to handle out of index exception then you can always verify the index item

```
extension Collection {
    /// Returns the element at the specified index if it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    public subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
      return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

There has already been an exhaustively answered similar question [Error-Handling in Swift-Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010569/error-handling-in-swift-language). Look at the first answer there which includes the latest updates in Swift 2.0 regarding this topic.

Comment: I mean the Uncaught Exception Handlers, rather than `try catch`

Comment: @Injoy - have you got the solution

Comment: This does not answer the question. The linked question is about user-level errors, this question is about catching and handling fatal errors. My research on the topic indicates that there currently is no equivalent way to catch fatal errors.